# Case wise Exception Handling in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I achieve below scenario using Oracle PL/SQL?

MY_STORED_PROC

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE1;  
  IF UPDATE1 fails RAISE EXCP1  
  ELSE COMMIT;

  UPDATE2;  
  IF UPDATE2 fails RAISE EXCP2  
  ELSE COMMIT;

EXCEPTION  
  WHEN EXCP1  
    INSERT LOG ('UPDATE1 Failed')  
  WHEN EXCP2  
    INSERT LOG ('UPDATE2 Failed')  
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite simple:

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    UPDATE1;
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE EXCP1;
  END;

  BEGIN
    UPDATE2;
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE EXCP2;
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN EXCP1 THEN
    INSERT LOG ('UPDATE1 Failed');
  WHEN EXCP2 THEN
    INSERT LOG ('UPDATE2 Failed');
END;
```

You can use `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` to define your own exceptions to be raised.